# Distributing VSPackage: is there something to pay to Microsoft?

Tags: visual-studio

Seems like one has to get an Id and register as Partner and for such pay a fee each year ?!

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458038(v=VS.90).aspx

> When you are ready to distribute your
>   VSPackage, you can obtain a PLK for it
>   by visiting the VSIP Members Web site.
>   You must have a Windows Live ID to log
>   on. After you log on, follow the
>   instructions to obtain a PLK. For more
>   information, see How to: Obtain a PLK
>   for a VSPackage.

When you go there:
http://www.mstoolspartners.com/anonymous/VSIP.aspx

> Need help choosing the right
>   membership level?
>
> Technology Partner Membership
>
> This level focuses on technical
>   enablement for companies who desire
>   development assistance with Visual
>   Studio. Annual fee: $2,000/year
>   (three-year contract)
>
> Preview the Microsoft Development
>   Tools Technology Partner contract
>
> Alliance Membership
>
> This level provides technical
>   enablement as well as a base business
>   and marketing relationship with
>   Microsoft. Annual fee: $3,000/year
>   (three-year contract)

Comment: From where did you get that idea?

Comment: see above Annual fee: $2,000/year

Comment: Microsoft is a bit picky about who gets a chance to crash their product.  There's lots of history of problems with add-ons.  I think the VSIP license terms changed for VS2010, click through to the .NET 4.0 article

Comment: "I think the VSIP license terms changed for VS2010": what do you mean? Is it since VS2010 that you have to pay or did it relax to free ?

Answer (score 1):

In recent years (i.e. since about 2003), **you do not need to pay anything to Microsoft to ship a Visual Studio extension**. The information you're looking at is outdated.

Today, the 'paid' VSIP program is only really for companies and groups that want additional marketing and technical benefits for supporting their Visual Studio extension.

To get a VSPackage to load properly in VS2002 - 2008, you **do** need a Package Load Key (PLK), but it's now just a matter of filling out a simple publicly accessible web form to get one (no payment or login required): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc655795